# django-guardian - AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-guardian

I'm trying to get django-guardian to work with my app. I followed the installation and configuration steps in the django-guardian documentation. It fails to assign permissions with the "ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed".

I've read the related Django docs and understand that the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting uses the "app_label.UserModel" format when using a custom user model. I'm not using a custom user model but the default django one.

All issues and solutions I found in the internets were related to custom user models which I don't think applies to me.

I'm using django 1.6.1 and django-guardian 1.1.1. dj-guardaian tutorial:

http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/assign.html

I tried to set the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'guardian.User' to no avail.

Any help appreciated!

Cheers

These are the exact steps (after importing settings):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> john = User.objects.get(id=2)
>>> john
<User: john>
>>> from mtm.models import Sharing
>>> obj = Sharing.objects.get(id=1)
>>> obj
<Sharing: Sharing object>
>>> john.has_perm('mtm.change_sharing', obj)
False
>>> from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
>>> assign_perm('mtm.change_sharing', john, obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    assign_perm('mtm.change_sharing', john, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guardian/shortcuts.py", line 71, in assign_perm
    user, group = get_identity(user_or_group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guardian/utils.py", line 73, in get_identity
    if isinstance(identity, get_user_model()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 129, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

settings.py

```
import os
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ss',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'djcelery',
    'mtm',
    'guardian',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'p4.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'p4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

#changed the default display formats
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'
TIME_FORMAT = 'H:i:s'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)    
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/kp/workspace/p4/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
```

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.auth` in your apps list?

Comment: yes, both 'django.contrib.auth' and 'guardian' are there. Just to add that user authentication in views works (I believe it uses .contrib.auth). Auth backends are configured as follows: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

Comment: posting your settings file would be useful imho

Comment: You're missing "south" from the list of apps/dependencies. Add it, then run "manage.py migrate" to complete the db.

Comment: Yes, that has fixed it. The django-guardian configuration instruction says to use the standard "syncdb". Is this something specific to my setup or should the guide be updated. I'm no familiar with South above the "schema migration" bit. Anyways thanks for your help!